# Number of transversals

Tags: combinatorics

Let $E=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and $S=(S_1,S_2,...,S_n)$ with $S_1=\{1,2\}, S_2=\{2,3\},...,S_{n-1}=\{n-1,n\}, S_n=\{n,1\}$. I'm asked to give the number of transversals of $S$.

---

I took the following approach: if you look at $S$ with $n$ subsets, there is one transversal, because you can take $n$ distinct elements from the subsets. If you look at $n-1$ subsets, there are $n$ possibilities to take away the $n$'th set. With $n-2$ there are $n \cdot (n-1)$, or $\frac{n!}{(n-2)!}$ transversals.
Continuing, you get that the total number of transversals is $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{n!}{(n-i)!}+1$.

Can anyone tell me if this is correct, and if not, where the error in my approach lies?

Answer (score 1):

Let $T(n)$ be the number of the transversals of $S$.

- If $n$ is odd, $T(n)=0$

Suppose there is a transversal. We choose $1$, wlog. Then, we cannot choose $2$, but we are ought to choose $3$, else $\{2,3\}$ will not have a representative. Continuing this way, we keep choosing odd numbers. Since, $n$ is odd, we have choose it. But, $\{n,1\}\in S$, a contradiction.

- If $n$ is even, $T(n)=2$

From the argument for the previous case, we either have to choose the odd numbers or the even numbers (arranged on a circle).

Comment: The way a transversal is defined in my book, it demands that you can find $n$ representatives that are all different. However, in your answer, you also demand that each pair of representatives doesn't have a common subset, correct?

Comment: Using your terminology, the usual [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transversal_%28combinatorics%29) of transversal is a subset of $E$ that contains exactly one element of $S_i$ for every $S_i\in S$. A representative of $S_i$ in $E$ is $S_i\cap E$, which is a singleton. Note that "you also demand that each pair of representatives doesn't have a common subset, correct?" does not make sense. Does this clear the air?